# Node.js 400 Bad request

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, supertest

I'm stuck with the 400 bad request when trying to POST to my mongo db, not knowing what's wrong with the code.

This is the structure in Mongoose:

```js
var exp = mongoose.model('Exp', {
    _creator: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true
    },

    exps: [{
        description: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        skillId: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            required: true
        }
    }]

});
```

This is my test case structure and it is how I want the data to be stored:

```js
const exp = {
    _creator: UserOneId, // an ObjectID
    exps:[{
        description: "Ate an apple",
        skillId: SkillOneId // an ObjectID
    },{
        description: "Took a shower",
        skillId: SkillTwoId // an ObjectID
    }],

};
```

The exps part should be an array to allow storing multiple exps, each with a description and a skill id.

Below is my POST function:

```js
app.post('/exps', authenticate, (req, res) => {

  var exp = new Exp({
    _creator: req.user._id, // got from suthenticate middleware
    exps: req.body.exps
  });
  exp.save().then(() => {
    res.send(exp);
  }, (e) => {
    res.status(400).send(e);
  });

})
```

and my test case:

```js
describe('POST /exps', () => {
    it('Should create new exp', (done) => {
        request(app)
            .post('/exps')
            .set('x-auth', users[0].tokens[0].token)
            .send(exps)
            .expect(200)
            .end(done);
    })
});
```

With a structure like this, I just can't figure out what went wrong that's giving me the 400, middleware & variables not mentioned here have passed with other test cases so I don't think it's those.

The error message in test looks like this:

```
1) POST /exps Should create new exp:
 Error: expected 200 "OK", got 400 "Bad Request"
  at Test._assertStatus (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:250:12)
  at Test._assertFunction (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:265:11)
  at Test.assert (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:153:18)
  at Server.assert (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:131:12)
  at emitCloseNT (net.js:1552:8)
  at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:77:11)
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you log `e` in the `.catch()` see if it helps

Comment: @Sridhar I tried that and it logged the same thing as the last part above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, found it. It was a typo in the POST function.